# Javascript how use array.filter on json array to return whole array if property matches a list

Tags: javascript, json

I need help on how do I filter an array,

Inside user_array I have arrays where I have to compare if the `header_info.sap_number` matches anything from `valid_sap_number array` ,

if that property value matches anything inside `valid_sap_number array`,

it will retain that array together with its parent array then remove all those other arrays that does not match any value from `valid_sap_number array`, I dont know how to explain it properly, so see my example instead, thank you,

I have array like these,

```
var valid_sap_number = ['1','2']
var user_array = 
[{
  "name":"User1",
  "header_info": [{ "sap_number":"1" }],
  "footer_info": [{ "site":"ABC" }]
}],
[{
  "name":"User2",
  "header_info": [{ "sap_number":"2" }],
  "footer_info": [{ "site":"ABCD" }]
}],
[{
  "name":"User3",
  "header_info": [{ "sap_number":"3" }],
  "footer_info": [{ "site":"ABC" }]
}];

/* This is my spaghetti code */

 const result = user_array.filter(user => function(a,b){        
            for(i = 0; i < valid_sap_number.length; i++)
            {
                if(b.header_info[0].sap_number == valid_sap_number[i]){
                    return true;     
                }
            }
        });

    console.log(result);
```

expected output

```
result =    [{
      "name":"User1",
      "header_info": [{ "sap_number":"1" }],
      "footer_info": [{ "site":"ABC" }]
    }],
    [{
      "name":"User2",
      "header_info": [{ "sap_number":"2" }],
      "footer_info": [{ "site":"ABCD" }]
    }];
```

Comment: What should happen when sub array is something like `[{"sap_number" : 1},{"sap_number" : 3}]` ??

Comment: @DRB it only has one sap_number per header_info, but it may have other properties, I dont know if it's ok to have this kind of array structure, I have about 100 properties, thats why I grouped it that way. thank you,!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `user_array` looks like not a valid array (no whole wrapper).

You can use `.filter()` in situations like this.

See below:

```js
var valid_sap_number = ['1','2']
var user_array = [
[{
  "name":"User1",
  "header_info": [{ "sap_number":"1" }],
  "footer_info": [{ "site":"ABC" }]
}],
[{
  "name": "User2",
  "header_info": [{ "sap_number": "2" }],
  "footer_info": [{ "site": "ABCD" }]
}],
[{
  "name": "User3",
  "header_info": [{ "sap_number":"3" }],
  "footer_info": [{ "site":"ABC" }]
}]
];

const result = user_array.filter(a => valid_sap_number.includes(a[0].header_info[0].sap_number))
```

Comment: can you explain me this code,
valid_sap_number.includes(a[0].header_info[0].sap_number)) 
why is it set to [0] ? how was it able to check the 3 array keys by setting it [0] , it worked but i  didnt get it, thank you,!

Comment: Basically, `include()` works on arrays checking if the given value is inside the array. The `a` here (sorry I did not use meaningful names) is your `user_array` single item representation, now based on your structure, `a` is another array inside an array and we expect it to only have 1 item so I specified to get `[0]` only. Same as `header_info` since you also made it an array, I need to get only the first index which is `[0]`

Comment: thank you bryan, i forgot i set it as an array,  thank you again,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array `includes` function inside the filter function to check if the current item matches any item in the list of values.

```
const result = user_array.filter(user => { 
  return valid_sap_number.includes(user[0].header_info[0].sap_number);
  });
```

Comment: thank you it worked, can you explain me how did it returned the whole array by just checking if valid_sap_number includes (user[0].header_info[0].sap_number) i thought it would just  return a valid_sap_number, thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I think you can improvise the JSON structure. The  current structure is somewhat misleading and incorrect for your  requirement.

**Proposal** :

```
user_array = [
   {
         "name" : "User1",
         "header_info": {
            "sap_number": 1,
            //... other properties of header_info
         },
         "footer_info" : {
             "site" : "ABC",
             //... other properties of footer_info
         }
   },


{
         "name" : "User2",
         "header_info": {
            "sap_number": 2,
            //... other properties of header_info
         },
         "footer_info" : {
             "site" : "ABCE",
             //... other properties of footer_info
         }
   }

]
```

and then make a filter like,

```
user_array.filter( user => valid_sap_number.includes(user.header_info.sap_number));
```

Comment: I can adjust the properties and remove the arrays,
 but I think I will have a hard time in making my users in that format due to I will have to adjust every object I added and the array mapping and a lot of processes I did with the data,,  Thank you for your suggestions I hope I can ask you more to simplify other parts of my code, thank you,

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (const user of user_array) {
    let result = [];
    const sapNumber = user.header_info[0].sap_number;
    foreach (const valid of valid_sap_number) {
        if (valid == sapNumber) {
            result.push(user);
        }
    }
}
user_array = result;
```